# Wordpress, Site Management and Testing

Tags: wordpress, testing, project-management

I have a very newb question. Mostly about the proper procedure to take regarding self hosted Wordpress.

I am a beginning web designer and of course - for practice - I offered to redesign a few of my friend websites.

I have my own self hosted Wordpress site as well.

How can I set it up so I can generate multiple sites as a sub directory to my site  - for my friends to review my design (using different themes for each).

If they like what I've done - I would then want to migrate it over to their hosts.

I do have a local implementation of Wordpress using MAMP - but most of my friends are in another state - and I would have to be able to show them the design via the web. 
Plus some of the Wordpress plugins (like Jetpack) only work on a live site.

Please advise the proper procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to install WordPress in a sub-directory on your web server for each site that you want to code out, with it's own MySQL database. No hassles with Multisite, and easy to backup and port to a new webhost when its ready to go live.

`http://your-url.com/friend-site-directory/`